# SQL group by concatenate string of a query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a query that joins several tables. In the result I have several fields, but I need to group by one of them concatenating the content of other field in a string.

The query result is like next table:

```
* query result
+-----------+-------------+
| element   |   option    |
+-----------+-------------+
|   25      |    foo 2    |
|   25      |    bar 1    |
|   25      |    baz 1    |
|   30      |    foo 2    |
|   30      |    baz 5    |
|   32      |    baz 1    |
+-----------+-------------+
```

I have done similar things before with `GROUP_CONCAT` like this:

```
SELECT
  result.element,
  GROUP_CONCAT(result.options SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'options'
FROM (
  -- place here an sql query with joins and some calculated fields --
) AS result
GROUP BY result.element
```

And it usually works, but it seems that the sql server that I have to do this query now, does not support `GROUP_CONCAT`.

The sql server version is *Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU8) (KB4037356) - 12.0.5557.0 (X64) Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)*

What I need in the end is something like this:

```
* final result
+-----------+-----------------------------+
| element   |   option                    |
+-----------+-----------------------------+
|   25      |    foo 2, bar 1, baz 1      |
|   30      |    foo 2, baz 5             |
|   32      |    baz 1                    |
+-----------+-----------------------------+
```

I've searched a lot and I found a way to do this directly from a table, but not from another query result. How it can be done?

EDIT: please, remember that I have to do the xml path from a query result, not from a table. I understand how to use it from a table, but I do not understand how to use the xml path from a query result.

If I use something like:

```
SELECT
  result.element,
  ( SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + options
    FROM result T2
    WHERE T2.element= result.element
    ORDER BY element
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') )AS 'options'
FROM (

  SELECT 
    st.element AS 'element',
    CONCAT(st.salesoriginid, ' ', COUNT(st.salesoriginid)) AS 'options'

  FROM SALESTABLE AS st WITH (NOLOCK)
  LEFT JOIN SALESLINE AS sl WITH (NOLOCK) ON sl.SALESID = st.SALESID AND sl.DATAAREAID = st.DATAAREAID
  LEFT JOIN INVENTDIM AS idim WITH (NOLOCK) ON idim.INVENTDIMID = sl.INVENTDIMID AND idim.DATAAREAID = sl.DATAAREAID

  WHERE st.salestype = 3
    AND st.salesoriginid IS NOT NULL
    AND st.salesoriginid != ''

  GROUP BY st.element, st.salesoriginid

) AS result
GROUP BY result.element
```

Then I get error:

```
Invalid object name 'result' [SQL State=S0002, DB Errorcode=208]
```

Comment: SQL Server does not support `GROUP_CONCAT`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server) for alternates.

Comment: sql server version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Stuff and 'For Xml Path' work in Sql Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)

Comment: *"but not from another query result"* what does this mean? Can you show the sample in your question please

Comment: @huMpty duMpty I mean that the origin of the data is no a table, is something like: `SELECT 
      st.element AS 'element',
      CONCAT(st.salesoriginid, ' ', COUNT(st.salesoriginid)) AS 'options'
    FROM SALESTABLE AS st WITH (NOLOCK)
    LEFT JOIN SALESLINE AS sl WITH (NOLOCK) ON sl.SALESID = st.SALESID AND sl.DATAAREAID = st.DATAAREAID
    LEFT JOIN INVENTDIM AS idim WITH (NOLOCK) ON idim.INVENTDIMID = sl.INVENTDIMID AND idim.DATAAREAID = sl.DATAAREAID
    WHERE st.salestype = 3
      AND st.salesoriginid IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY st.element, st.salesoriginid`

Comment: @Alex: So you can try creating temp table and execute this as [dynamic sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and then writing the final query in temp table

Comment: @huMpty duMpty maybe it's something wrong with the link, it's for an execute transact sql for a sql server 2017. I've never used dynamic sql.... I think I should search and read aboput it

Comment: @Alex here you go small sample. `Create Table #T(Id int, Something varchar(10))
Declare @Query varchar(max) = 'Select 10, ''Desc1'' Union Select 11, ''Desc2'''
SET @Query = 'INSERT INTO #t ' +  @Query
exec (@Query)
sELECT *
FROM #t`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 concatenate rows to column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922448/sql-server-2008-concatenate-rows-to-column)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
Select Distinct element, (
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' +option
FROM #T T2
Where T2.element = T1.element
ORDER BY element
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') )AS [Options]
From #T T1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select element,option= stuff((select ',' + option from table t1 where 
t1.element=t2.element for xml path ('')),'',1,1) from table t2
group by element
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a CTE?

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select e.element,
       stuff( (select ',' + t2.option
               from t t2
               where t2.element = e.element
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, ''
            ) as options
from (select distinct element from t) e;
```

You can probably simplify this by pulling the elements directly from a base table.